# How to prove the existence of odd numbers $a$ and $b$ in $2m\equiv a^{20}+b^{11}\pmod{2^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that for any natural numbers $m,n$, there exist odd numbers $a,b$ such that
>   $$2m\equiv a^{20}+b^{11}\pmod{2^n}$$

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Thank you everyone help me edit,sorry, my English is very poor.

Comment: Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ be the group of units of integers modulo $n$. It has $|G| = \varphi(2^n) = 2^{n-1}$ elements. Since $\gcd(2^{n-1},11) = 1$, $G$ doesn't contain any element of order $11$. As a result, the map $b \mapsto b^{11}$ is a group monomorphism and hence a group automorphism. For any $m$ and any odd $a$, $2 m - a^{20} \in G$ and hence we can find a $b$ such that $2 m - a^{20} \equiv b^{11} \pmod{2^n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We proceed by induction on $n$.

When $n=1$, we have $1^{20}+1^{11} \equiv 0 \equiv 2m \pmod{2^1}$.

Suppose that the statement holds for $n=k$, so $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a, b$ odd, such that $2m \equiv a^{20}+b^{11} \pmod{2^k}$. Thus $a^{20}+b^{11} \equiv 2m, 2m+2^k \pmod{2^{k+1}}$. If $a^{20}+b^{11} \equiv 2m \pmod{2^{k+1}}$, we are done. Otherwise we have $a^{20}+b^{11} \equiv 2m+2^k \pmod{2^{k+1}}$. Then $a^{20}+(b+2^k)^{11} \equiv a^{20}+b^{11}+11b^{10}2^k \equiv (a^{20}+b^{11})+2^k \equiv 2m \pmod{2^{k+1}}$.  We are thus done by induction.

Therefore for any $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there exist odd $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2m \equiv a^{20}+b^{11} \pmod{2^n}$.

Comment: oh,It's very nice.

Comment: I have qustion, this problem can induction by $m$?

Comment: and this problem $a$ is odd numbers can delete?